# Issues with extracting URLs from text

Tags: python, regex, url, nlp

I am trying to find a regular expression to extract any valid URLs (not only http[s]) using a regular expression. Unfortunately, each one outputs weird things. The best results I achieved using this regex:

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w\-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]|\((?:[^\s()<>]|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()<>]|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

But I can mark at least the following issues:

- http://208.206.41.61/email/email_log.cfm?useremail=3Dtana.jones@enron.com&=refdoc=3D(01-128) is extracted as http://208.206.41.61/email/email_log.cfm?useremail=3Dtana.jones@enron.com&=
- http://www.onlinefilefolder.com',AJAXTHRESHOLD should be extracted without AJAXTHRESHOLD
- CSS / HTML styling is extracted, for example `xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt, ze:12px;color:#666, font-size:12px;color` etc

How can I improve this regex to make sure only valid URLs are extracted? I am not only extracting it from the HTML, but also from a plain text. Therefore, using only `beautifulsoup` is impossible for my use case.

Comment: try it:     'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'

Comment: Here's a website about url regexp [urlregex.com](https://urlregex.com/)

Comment: @Glitch__ already tried with this one. The provided regex causes many more issues. Regex presented in the question is probably the best one I found so far, but also has its cons

Comment: @Unreboot does not work with "http://www.onlinefilefolder.com',AJAXTHRESHOLD"

Answer (score 0):

No regex is perfect, but this one might help you:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])
```

Flag to enable: insensitive, global, multiline (**igm**)

Source: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

Comment: Does not work with any of the above examples

Comment: Try with igm (insensitive, global, multi line) flags.
It is working for me. (https://regex101.com/)